# Multiple values in POST requests in django view not working

Tags: python, django, forms, post, request

I have three different buttons for different purposes (inserts & deletes from a table), each one should handle a different value in POST. I managed to do it once with

*if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("name_of_button", "") == 'value_of_button'*

But when I use the same idea again for a different button it just doesn't work. The code inside every condition works fine, it's just not getting into the if when I add the second condition.

**views.py**

```
def listpolls(request):

    #mysql connection here#

    form = AddPollForm()
    form_del = DelPollForm()

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("btn_add_name", "") == 'btn_add_val':

        form = AddPollForm(request.POST)
        form_del = DelPollForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            ip = form.cleaned_data['poll_ip']
            #poll_time = form.... etc

            #whatever you want to do here#

            return HttpResponseRedirect('listpolls.html')

        else:

            return render_to_response("listpolls.html",{"buffer_data": b, 'form': form, 'form_del': form_del} )        

    elif request.method == 'POST':

         #whatever you want to do here#

        return HttpResponseRedirect('listpolls.html')

    elif request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("btn_delbyip_name", "") == 'btn_delbyip_val':

         #whatever you want to do here#

            return HttpResponseRedirect('listpolls.html')

        else:

            return HttpResponseRedirect('listpolls.html')   

    else:
        return render_to_response("listpolls.html",{"buffer_data": b, 'form': form, 'form_del': form_del} )
```

**template**

```
<form action="/services/listpolls/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form }}

    <button type="submit" value="btn_add_val" name="btn_add_name">Añadir</button>

</form> 

<form action="/services/listpolls/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form_del }}

   <button type="submit" value="btn_delbyip_val" name="btn_delbyip_name">Borrar por IP</button>

   </form>

    <form action="/services/listpolls/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
           <button type="submit" value="{{b.id}}" name="btn_borrar" class="delete_poll">Borrar</button>
         </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With removing all unrelevant code, you have your 'if' logic structure like this:

```
def listpolls(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("btn_add_name", "") == 'btn_add_val':
        pass
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    elif request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("btn_delbyip_name", "") == 'btn_delbyip_val':
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

Explaining that structure:
First if will check if request is POST and if some POST parameter have desired value. If yes, it will compute something and leave whole structure. If not, it will continue to next elif.

Second will check if request is POST. If yes, it will compute something and leave whole structure. If not, it will continue to next elif.

Third will check if request is POST and if some POST parameter have desired value. If yes, it will compute something and leave whole structure. If not it will continue to else.

Else will compute something and leave that structure of if's.

Now we can clearly see what is happening here, if first condition wasn't true  and this is post request, second condition will ALWAYS be true! So third condition won't be even checked. You should simply swap second and third conditions (with whole code attached to it) and it will work.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed when removing all the unnecessary code and focusing on that, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple logic error. Every case where the action is a POST but the button is not "btn_add_val" is caught by the first elif. If you want to catch the "btn_delbyip_name" you should move that to before that elif.